# Event Listener function not returning any value

Tags: javascript

I am lost and I would like to understand where is my error, or what should I check to figure it out.

I am building a simple Rock Scissors game. I can't return any values from Event Listener function to a variable.
Console.log returns undefined.

```
function listeningToPlayer () {
    const btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
    btn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener ('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.innerHTML == "Rock") {
        return "rock"
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "Paper"){
        return "paper";
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "Scissors") {
        return "scissors";
    }
}))
}
// Variables with computer and player choices
let computer_selection = computerPlay()
let player_selection = listeningToPlayer()


console.log(player_selection)
```

Thanks in advance.
Also, if someone could tell me if my Event Listener is very bad, I would be grateful. "innerHTML" was the best way I could figure out.

If my coding is ridiculous, sorry for that - I have started few days ago!

Comment: `forEach` doesnt returns anything and I see no point of returning anything from callback function,you can execute your logic directly inside callback

Comment: `addEventListener` only adds a listener. It doesn't wait until the event is fired. Your `console.log(player_selection)` will be executed _before_ any click event is fired.

Comment: Recommend learning about the event loop, it will help you understand how asynchronous things like event listeners work. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) for a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An event listener is a function that gets executed when an event happens. In this case a click. You register what must happen when the click occurs. In this case you like to update the game state with the selected value.

A more standard way of setting data on a html element is using the `data` attribute. For example: `<button data-choice="paper">Paper</button>`.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" data-choice="paper">Paper</button>
<button class="btn" data-choice="scissors">Scissors</button>
<button class="btn" data-choice="rock">Rock</button>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Js:

```
const randomChoice = () => (['paper', 'scissors', 'rock'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);

const gameState = {
  player: null,
  computer: randomChoice()
}

const out = document.querySelector('#output');
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

out.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(gameState, null, 2)

for (const btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    gameState.player = e.target.dataset.choice;
    out.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(gameState, null, 2);
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h0z5vf7y/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle data in this way. The only possibility is to handle them inside callback given to event listener.

```js
const handleUserClick = ( player_selection ) => {
    if ( player_selection === "Rock" ) {
        // do something here
    } else { /* ... */ }
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
buttons.forEach( btn => btn.addEventListener 'click', (e) => handleUserClick( e.target.innerHTML) ) )
```